# Problem GITEA´s ssh (docker) ON DSM 7 (synology)

Tags: git, docker, ssh, synology

I´ve got a problem and I wonder, if anybody could help here:

I want to install gitea with mysql as docker-compose on my synology with DSM 7, but I´m not able to get the ssh working

In short my setup (not the real info, but consistent :-))

```
Synology: 192.168.1.5 
ssh port: 10222 
user (that runs container): git (1058) 
shell: ssh-shell script which does this:


#!/bin/sh
shift
ssh -p 19022 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no git@127.0.0.1 "SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND=\"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\" $@"
```

gitea docker:

```
user that runs in container: git (1058)
ssh port: 19022
volume mounts:
 - data
 - ~/.ssh folder from host user
```

The idea with the mount of the .ssh folder of the host user into the container is, that when I add a ssh key in gitea for a user it should be added also on host level, so the ssh connect with the user can work first on host and then in the container

As far as I understood it the flow is like this.

1. user adds his ssh key in his account settings in gitea
2. ssh key is added in container in the mounted .ssh folders authorized_keys
3. therefore it´s also available on hosts user (git) authorized keys and is recognized when someone makes a git clone ssh://git@192.168.1.5 (the machine from which I´m doing this, must have an .ssh/config file set up with the necessary settings like (hostname, port, identityfile) in place

Thing is, when I´m doing all this, and try to connect from another machine with the right private key of the public key I added to the giteas web ui, I´m getting a password challenge as if I didn´t provide an identityfile.

somewhere in that chain is a typo, misunderstanding, whatever that drives me nuts big time :-(

Any hints how to approach this ?

Thanks in advance and Greetings,

Wurzelseppi

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Git. I've never used Synology but I've heard some stuff about it, and I think this is entirely a Synology issue: as I understand it they have some special, custom version of the ssh server that's weird is some fashion. (But that's all I know.) I added the [tag:synology] tag here.

Comment: I can ssh into host (with normal shell '/bin/bash') and I can ssh into container directly (exposed ssh port), and i can clone an repo from gitea when connecting directly to the container, but I don´t want to expose the ssh port of the container to outside ..... it should work with this ssh-shell, or docker-shell like explained here https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/install-with-docker/#sshing-shell-with-authorized_keys
But, It doesn´t :-(

Comment: Given what I've heard and some guesses, my guess would be that the Synology ssh doesn't support the same env variables and restrictions that regular ssh does. Most Git servers that use ssh use the `command=...` trick in the `authorized_keys` file to limit access.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to clone repositories from a gitea instance running on a Synology DS218 (not a docker installation, manual, but very similar setup noneless), configured to use the NAS ssh server (not the gitea builtin ssh server).

The trick for me was to set access rights for the home and ssh directory of the user running the gitea instance:

```
sudo chown -R gitea:users /volume1/homes/gitea
sudo chmod 0600 /volume1/homes/gitea/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chmod 0700 /volume1/homes/gitea/.ssh
sudo chmod 0755 /volume1/homes/gitea
```

As a side note, only users member of group 'admin' are able to use SSH on Synology NAS.

While this is the recommended way of doing by the constructor, I choosed to not add 'gitea' user to 'admin' group for security reason. To be able to connect using ssh, I modifyed `/etc/passwd` (but you can choose to go the 'standard' way and ignore this):

```
gitea:x:1028:100:Gitea (System user):/var/services/homes/gitea:/bin/sh
```